# My wordpress will not load thumbnails photos

Tags: wordpress

hey everyone im tying to use this this theme but it will not load the thumbnail for any post can you guys please help me out?

the site is http://sourceplanet.net

im totally lost on why it wont load.

Answer (score 5):

Which post are you talking about?